# Cannot Resolve Symbol @+id/ in .xml when using android:below_

Tags: android, xml

I try to add a button into my layout. The layout previously does not contain any errors. But after I drag and drop the button into the layout, it shows an error as the picture below.

[image: Cannor Resolve symbol "@+id/checksensortextview"]

Even I already define @+id/checksensortextview .

Here is the code before and after I add the button. (Even I remove the added button, the errors still there).

[image: Before and After add button into textview]

I add the button in activity_evaluate.xml, but it affect every .xml file except activity_login.xml

Is anybody face the problem like this before?
Thank you for any solutions and suggestions.

Comment: Just for future, its only for defining an id for the first time, you need to you `@+id/`. For referencing it later, you use just `@id/yourId`

Comment: You still haven't clear when to reference an id by using `@id` and when to use `@+id`...

Comment: I think he was : just imagine that '+' sign is necessary to create it.

Answer (score 11):

`Invalidate Caches and Restart` cleared that error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Build clean resolve that question for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had this problem. Did you just move your project? Because I did. And it turned out that I had some old paths in your config files (idea and gradle configs).

I fixed it by copying my project folder to a new location and re-imported the project.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I don't know what exactly can be the cause of this problem!

I fixed it by opening the xml file and going to `Build` then `Recompile your_xml_file.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
I tried to run my app, and it did, despite it was highlighted red. So looks like a bug - I relaunched android studio and everything was ok. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I did **Build > Rebuild Project** in Android Studio to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are currently on the wrong variant of the app.
Once you change your build variant the XML will load the changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using multiple `ComposeView`s in the same layout and hence needed to add the `id`s for those views to the `ids.xml` file as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/compose-in-views#multiple-composeviews).
Once I did that, the issue was resolved.